# How to get url in <a> tag with Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, dom, domparser

```
<ul id="PrList" class="v2">
    <li class="tools">

    </li>
    <li class="firstRow">
        <div class="i">
            <a href="www.google.com" title="Google" class="nC">
                <img src="something">
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to get just `href` attribute in `<div class="i">`?

I tried this-

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
$urls = [];
foreach($html->find('.i') as $element) {
   $url = $element->find('.nC')->href;
   if (!in_array($url, $urls)) {
       echo $url . "<br/>";
       $urls[] = $url;
   }
}
```

but I received an error:-

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

and I tried:-

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
$html = $html->find('div.i');
$html -> find('a',0)->href; 
$echo $html;
```

but I received an error again:-

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on array

Comment: `$url = $element->find('a')->href;` try it

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
$urls = [];
foreach($html->find('.i a') as $element) {
   $url = $element->href;
   if (!in_array($url, $urls)) {
       echo $url . "<br/>";
       $urls[] = $url;
   }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($urls);
```

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I struggled for a day to solve this problem. I am very happy now. I'm sorry for my bad english. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop.

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=i] a') as $a){
  var_dump($a->attr);
}
```